# Xcode - UICollectionView inside UIViewController

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, collectionview

I'm trying to insert a collection view inside a UIViewController:

```
import UIKit

class imagesViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var labels = ["label1", "label2", "label3"]

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

    }




    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
        return labels.count
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

        // Configure the cell

        var title = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.size.height))
        cell.contentView.addSubview(title)

        title.text = labels[indexPath.row]
        title.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

        return cell
    }
```

The app runs but it doesn't seem that the collection view is linked properly to the class, none of the configurations I made works,it just appears blank. Strangely enough I had to copy/paste the functions for the collection view because the autocomplete only shows some of the collectionview methods.

Answer (score 3):

If you created your cells using StoryBoard, then I had this same problem and was able to solve it by removing

```
self.collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

That line, if you defined a cell in StoryBoard, seems to duplicate efforts and block any of the cells from displaying.